# How to add UIBarButtonItem action in Popoverview?

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem, uipopover

i want to show popoverview with UIBarButtonItem action but i cannot add popover segue in storyboard. Because i added UIBarButtonItem programmatically.

Thanks in replies.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIPopoverController *yourPopOverController;
```

In your action Method.

```
 UIBarButtonItem *yourButton = (UIBarButtonItem *)sender;

 YourViewController *yourViewControllerObject = [[YourViewController alloc]init];

        yourPopOverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:yourViewControllerObject];
        yourPopOverController.delegate = self;
        [yourPopOverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:yourButton permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I couldn't do it from your codes. How can I create popover from storyboard. But My storyboard must have custom uibarbutton items. Here is photo link explain my situation  (http://i.stack.imgur.com/SjsL6.png)

Comment: have u added uibarbuttonitem in ur viewController.

Comment: if u have added then create a segue for that another button also.

Comment: Yes,i did in viewDidload.

Comment: if u have added in viewDidload then u have to show popover programatically.

Comment: when I use popover segue in storyboard, xcode say that popover segue with no anchor. Because I added uibarbuttonitem programmatically.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67892/discussion-between-dheeraj-singh-and-fozoglu).